# How to get and process json data given by ajax request in prototype?

Tags: php, javascript, prototypejs

This is my first attempt to prototype. I want to initiate an AJAX request that should get a JSON response and alert that. I have done following so far.

**JS:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function ajaxRequest() {

    var url = '/ajaxresponse';

    new Ajax.Request( url, {

         method: 'get',
         onSuccess: function(transport,json) {
            alert(json ? Object.inspect(json) : "no JSON object");  
         },     
         onFailure: function(){ 
            alert('Something went wrong...') 
         }  
    });
}

</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<a href='javascript:ajaxRequest();'>Testing AJAX</a>
```

**JSON source:**

```
function ajaxresponse() {

    // Data
    $data = array("New York", "New Yorkshire", "New Jersey");
    // encode and return json data
    echo json_encode( $data );
}
```

On clicking "**Testing AJAX**" link I am getting following result in alert box:

```
no JSON object
```

Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont see any second variable passed to onSuccess handler in prototype. Look [here](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/ajax/request). There is only transport object. So this should help:

```
...
onSuccess: function(transport) {
      var json = transport.responseText;
      alert(json ? Object.inspect(json) : "no JSON object");  
 }, 
...
```

Comment: oh. ok. It is not alerting now `no JSON object`.. But it is alerting me whole file with js code in response.. It does not look json and I want to get only cities in json.. Posting current result in next comment:

Comment: `
<script type="text/javascript">


function ajaxRequest() {

 var url = '/ajaxresponse';

 new Ajax.Request( url, {

    method: 'get',
    onSuccess: function(transport) {
   var json = transport.responseText;
        alert(json ? Object.inspect(json) : "no JSON object");  
    },     
        onFailure: function(){ 
         alert('Something went wrong...') 
     }  
 });
}

</script>

["New York","New Yorkshire","New Jersey"]`

Comment: its weird, what is the result of alert(transport.responseText); and alert(transport.headerJSON)?

Comment: `null` for `alert(transport.headerJSON)` and whole page html with js and json for `alert(transport.responseText)` like my 2nd comment above....

Comment: I am not a PHP expert, but I have a bad feeling that you have both parts in the same file. If not, post whole files PHP and client HTML/JS.

Comment: You realy should split it. Its a good habbit to keep backend and frontened separated. AFAIK when php is processed all content is outputed (echoed or printed out). Thats why you can see/use your HTML/js for the first time. For testing purposes you can add some parameter to the url and skip HTML/JS block in your PHP file if is present and echo out the cities array othewise.